# Proving a piecewise function is Riemann Integrable $f(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 2$ for $x ∈ (0, 1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> If $f : [0, 1] → \mathbb R$ is a function such that $f(x) = 0$ for $x
>  = 0$ and $f(x) = 2$ for $x ∈ (0, 1]$. Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.

Here, I thought to divide the partition in to equal subintervals and consider two cases, where $0 \in [x_{k-1} , x_{k}]$ and $0$ not in the $k^{th}$ subinterval.

when $x \neq 0 , f(x) = 2 $ hence $U(f) = L(f) = 2$ when $0 \in [x_{k-1} , x_{k}] , L(f) = 0$ and $U(f) = sup \{\dfrac{2}{n} \}$ the limit is still $0$

is there a better way to say this is Riemann Integrable?

Comment: $0$ is always in the first interval $[x_0, x_1]$. (Suppose the partition is $0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_{n-1}<x_n=1$.) Hence in every interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$  where $i\ne 1$, $\sup f=\inf f=2$. If $i=1$, this interval “contributes” the delta of upper and lower Darboux sum by $2x_1=2(x_1-x_0)$, which shall converges to $0$ as $\max (x_{i+1}-x_i)$ converges to $0$. As for your answer, where does the $\dfrac{2}{n}$ come from?

Comment: It might be easier if you can tell us the definition of Riemann integrability you can use?